# How to create ActivityIndicator when I scroll in a Flatlist , to see each card Image correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to create  component in each card when I scroll my Flatlist. Each card calls an API to get the Image, My problem is when I scroll each card shows a background opacity and a white card while charging.

MoviesFlatList.tsx

```
export const MoviesFlatList = ({ title, movies }: Props) => {

return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { height: (title) ? 260 : 210 }]}>

        {
            title && <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 7 }}>{title}</Text>
        }
        <Animated.FlatList
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            data={movies}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <MovieCardFlatList
                    movie={item}
                    height={200}
                    width={140}
                />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            horizontal={true}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            decelerationRate={0}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            bounces={false}

        />
    </View>
)
```

}

MoviesCardFlatlist.tsx

```
export const MovieCardFlatList = ({ movie, height = 420, width = 300 }: Props) => {

const uri = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}`;

const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParams>>();

return (

    <Pressable
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', movie)}
        //activeOpacity={0.8}
        style={{
            width,
            height,
            marginHorizontal: 2,
            paddingBottom: 20,
            paddingHorizontal: 7
        }}


    >
        <Animated.View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
                source={{ uri }}
                style={styles.image}
            />
        </Animated.View>
    </Pressable>
)
```

}[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with this property to false

```
<Animated.FlatList
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
```